# Memory ordering or read-modify-write operation with (read/write)-only memory order

Tags: c++, concurrency, synchronization, atomic, memory-barriers

Executing the following is an atomic RMW operation

```
auto value = atomic.fetch_or(value, order);
```

When `order` is `std::memory_order_acq_rel` we know that the load of the previous value in the atomic will acquire any release operations that might have happened previously on the same atomic.  And the write will release the current thread's writes for threads that acquire the same atomic variable.  Same with `std::memory_order_seq_cst`.

But what is the expected behavior of the write part of the RMW operation with respect to memory ordering when you use `std::memory_order_acquire`?  Similarly, what is the expected behavior of using `std::memory_order_release` for the load side of the RMW operation?

Comment: It has the semantics as specified by `order`, unsurprisingly, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @PasserBy What does a `memory_order_release` specify for a read operation?  What happens to the read end of a RMW operation when a `memory_order_release` is used?

Comment: Nothing, but `fetch_or` counts as a write as well.

Comment: @PasserBy sure, but if I use the previous value in the atomic for some logic.  Can I assume that the current thread has synchronized with any other release operations?  Or is the read relaxed?

Comment: The `fetch_or` is _one_ operation, not a separate read and write. If there happens to be an acquire somewhere down the line, then a `fetch_or` with release semantics will synchronize with that later read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `std::memory_order_acquire` on an atomic RMW is an acquire-only operation.
Since it does not 'release' anything, it cannot be part of a synchronizes-with relationship with another atomic acquire operation (on the same atomic variable) that occurs later.
Therefore, the equivalent for the store part is `std::memory_order_relaxed`

Similar reasoning for using `std::memory_order_release` on an RMW. It does not acquire anything, so the ordering equivalent for the load part is 'relaxed'

Comment: @PasserBy If that is meant to be cynical, take it somewhere else

Comment: Um... cynical how? What did I say?